# react-native find out if a component is visible again

Tags: reactjs, react-native

- Suppose you are showing component A,
- Then you navigate to component B (a new activity in android).
- By back-pressing, B goes out, and you get back to A

Is there a way for A to get notified of the event of the return ?

`useEffect(()=>{},[])` only fires for the first render..

I'm not using `react-navigation`

Comment: you can pass props from component B to A while navigating through the same using `react-router`

Answer (score -2):

If you are using the `react-navigation` library then you can use the `useFocusEffect` hook. [5.x docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect)

Or there are also navigation events that you can listen to. [5.x docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/) and [4.x docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigation-events/)

Comment: unfortunately i'm not